# AngularJS unit testing module conflicts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have a few modules with code in different places based on where it is necessary:

```
angular.module('hthsLunch.landingPage', [
  'hthsLunch.core.authService',
  'hthsLunch.core.messageService'
]);
angular.module('hthsLunch.user', ['hthsLunch.core.authService']);
angular.module('hthsLunch.order', [
  'hthsLunch.core.itemService',
  'hthsLunch.core.orderService',
  'hthsLunch.core.userService',
  'hthsLunch.core.authService',
  'hthsLunch.core.databaseService'
]);
angular.module('hthsLunch.panel', [
  'ngResource',
  'hthsLunch.core.messageService'
]);

angular.module('hthsLunch', [
  'ngMaterial',
  'ui.router',
  'hthsLunch.landingPage',
  'hthsLunch.user',
  'hthsLunch.order',
  'hthsLunch.panel'
]).config(['$locationProvider', '$mdThemingProvider',
  function($locationProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
    $locationProvider
      .html5Mode(true)
      .hashPrefix('!');

    $mdThemingProvider
      .theme('default')
      .primaryColor('blue')
      .accentColor('green');
  }
]);
```

I'm trying to test a filter in the module `hthsLunch.panel`, but I can't do `beforeEach(module('hthsLunch.panel'));` because that causes module dependency errors. I can't do `beforeEach(module('hthsLunch'))` for some reason because then the filter seems to be undefined. How can I properly write unit tests with this module structure?

Comment: The correct way to test your filter is the first way you suggest - loading just the `hthsLunch.panel` module on which it is defined. If there are "module dependency errors" doing this, make sure those missing dependencies have been loaded along with karma.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to load ui-router though, because I'm not using that in the .panel module. Is there a better way to organize the modules?

Comment: ui-router is not a dependency of `hthsLunch.panel` though? If it is so indirectly (through `hthsLunch.core.messageService`) then you could consider refactoring that module's dependencies. A 'service' module probably shouldn't need a router as a dependency.

Comment: I'm declaring some routes in the .panel module, so it depends on having access to `$stateProvider`.